# How does ARAM random pick work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Curious if ARAM random pick is based off your owned champions or all 100+ champions. Have only gotten a chance to play 1 game and it seemed like it was based off my own champions but half my team said they were playing champs for the first time.

Comment: People can buy champions on sale or in packs and never play them.

Comment: I assume it is a good question. The answer was fairly predictable but still, it is a good plus to the knowledge of the site about this topic. +1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ARAM champion selection is based only off of champions currently available to you. This includes all champions you own, plus all the ones that are available free at the time.

Comment: not the answer i was hoping for, not nearly as fun as getting a champion i've never touched.

Comment: There isn't a way to ever do that in any game mode/map as far as I know.

Comment: how in the world do you get 11 ponts for 2 sentences...i usually have to write a novel with pictures to get anything like that...

Comment: I don't know but it felt like i only get those champions I only rarely play (which is only a small amount)

Comment: @Paralytic I know, right? I've had like half a dozen research answers with multiple paragraphs and stuff for 5 or less, but have 12 for this... Not that I'm complaining of course :)